# python dict to matrix using implict feedback approach

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, matrix-factorization

I'm seeking to configure the best model for measuring implicit feedback given my nested dictionary of unique users and the number of plays per artist listened to. I've tried a few values but they appear only cosmetic, and not measurable.

Sample data:

```
    users                                       artist   plays
0   00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89    korn     12763
1   00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89    sting    8192
2   00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89    nirvana  6413
```

Source code:

```
user_artist_dict = user_artist_plays.groupby('users').apply(lambda user_artist_plays: dict(zip(user_artist_plays.artist, user_artist_plays.plays))).to_dict()
```

I want a matrix factoring `0` plays if user did not listen to artist, and if they had it inserts the `plays`.

My initial intention was to use DictVectorizer with sklearn but it's giving me trouble with `artist` strings.

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question?

Comment: @iliatimofeev i have not really, no. do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Yes i've got:) sorry for misleading, take a look on update 3 it`s much simpler than it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sparse version.**
Current version of `pandas` has limited support of sparse data, you can call `pd.get_dummies(sparse=True)` and it will return some `SparseDataFrame` but as result of most of manipulation it will be transformed back to `DataFrame`. 
Sparse versions of `unstack` and `pivot_table` are still in [roadmap](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14493).
So we should use other libraries to solve it, for example sklearn has [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) with the same functionality as `pd.get_dummies` but it can return `scipy.sparse` matrix. Then with help of small algebra tricks we can achieve the goal.

---

Test data sample will help check correctness of calculations:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
             ['a1', 11, 'u1'], ['a3', 23, 'u2'], ['a2', 22, 'u2'],
             ['a3', 33, 'u3'], ['a1', 31, 'u3'], ['a2', 32, 'u3'],
             ['a5', 45, 'u4'], ['a4', 44, 'u4'], ['a3', 43, 'u4'],
             ['a2', 42, 'u4']], columns =['artist', 'plays', 'users'])
print(df.pivot_table(values='plays',index='users',
                     columns='artist',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0))
```

output

```py
artist  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
users                     
u1      11   0   0   0   0
u2       0  22  23   0   0
u3      31  32  33   0   0
u4       0  42  43  44  45
```

The same result but sparse

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from scipy.sparse import diags
lb_artist = LabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)
lb_user = LabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)
X = lb_user.fit_transform(df.users).T*(diags(df.plays)*lb_artist.fit_transform(df.artist))
print(type(X),'shape:',X.shape,'values:',X.nnz,'data:')
print(X)
```

Output. For test sample it should be `(user,artist)     10*(user+1)+artist+1`

```py
<class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'> shape: (4, 5) values: 10 data:
  (2, 0)    31.0
  (0, 0)    11.0
  (3, 1)    42.0
  (2, 1)    32.0
  (1, 1)    22.0
  (3, 2)    43.0
  (2, 2)    33.0
  (1, 2)    23.0
  (3, 3)    44.0
  (3, 4)    45.0
```

`lb_user` and `lb_artist` store string values of keys it can be used to recover original frame.

```py
print(
    pd.DataFrame(X.todense(),index=lb_user.classes_,columns=lb_artist.classes_)
    )
```

Output:

```py
         a1    a2    a3    a4    a5
    u1  11.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
    u2   0.0  22.0  23.0   0.0   0.0
    u3  31.0  32.0  33.0   0.0   0.0
    u4   0.0  42.0  43.0  44.0  45.0
```

---

Comment: the `scipy.sparse` matrix can be used with `KNeighborsClassifier` right?

Comment: According to documentation [fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.fit) accepts space matrix.
You can play with `metric` parameter to get some results, but at general its not a best way to do recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 3** Usual way to do it is by [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) function.

```py
df.pivot_table(values='plays',index='users',columns='artist',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)
```

Or [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) will be more effective in that case

```py
df.set_index(['users','artist']).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Or my crazy way

```py
res = pd.get_dummies(df.artist) 
res.loc[:,:]=res.values*df.plays.values.reshape(-1,1)
#make 'users' index 
res.join(df.users).groupby('users').sum()
```

Output:

```py
users                                       korn    nirvana sting
00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89    12763   8192    6413
```

-

Comment: how would i take your code and make the user the index? `res.set_index('users')`?

Comment: Yep. But better `df.set_index('user',inplace=True)` before and remove last line. But in sample they are not unique...

Comment: how to remove last line?

Comment: I found better solution :) now rows is users

Comment: it's throwing me `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'artist'` since my data type is `dict`

Comment: `df = user_artist_plays`

Comment: revised code below to show where i am, but its throwing me an error `ValueError: shapes (21520,) and (53097,) not aligned: 21520 (dim 0) != 53097 (dim 0)`

Comment: I made a fix, if it would not help publish a link to you data sample.

Comment: I took one more look to your question :). I don't know where I was while writing the answer, but there is much simpler answer to your question.

Comment: does a pivot table permit for alternating least squares for collaborative filtering? i've attempt to use scipy sparse, but perhaps pivot table does the job? thoughts?

Comment: I've posted another answer for "sparce" part of question. I haven't seen direct implementation of collaborative filtering in common libraries but you surely can implement using `scipy` or `sklearn`. There are some public implementations but didn't use them so i can't recommend. Try with `sparse.linalg.spsolve` than you could ask on [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).